# Inspect a NullPointerException cause

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I have an ArrayList of a certain class which i try to sort, However i get a NullPointerException during the sort.
I wrapped my command with a try-catch in order to find which element in the array causes the exception.
How can i inspect the catch in order to figure out which is the problematic element?

Following is the code:

```
List<SingleMeasurementValuePoint> sortedList = new ArrayList<SingleMeasurementValuePoint>(deviceMeasurementPoints);
    try {
      Collections.sort(sortedList, new TimeAndComponentSort());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The code within the comparator, i.e TimeAndComponentSort is:

```
public class TimeAndComponentSort implements Comparator<SingleMeasurementValuePoint> {

@Override
public int compare(SingleMeasurementValuePoint point1, SingleMeasurementValuePoint point2) {
    int val = point1.compareTo(point2);
    if (val == 0) {
        return point1.getComponentId().compareTo(point2.getComponentId());
    }
    else {
        return val;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use a debugger?

Comment: You could post your code in the comparator - TimeAndComponentSort.

Comment: I use a debugger, and stand inside the catch. How can i detect which one of the 4500 elements within the ArrayList is the cause for the exception?

Comment: How about loop through the list to find out the null before sorting?

Comment: I tried looping through the list and didn't find an explicit null value: for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
    if (sortedList.get(i).getTimestamp() == null) {
     System.out.println();
    }
   }

Comment: Why not do e.printStackTrace(); ?

Comment: do e.printStachTrace() within the expression evaluation? If so, that produces "result=undefined"

Comment: In eclipse I can set a break point on a type of exception. So I can see where it will be thrown in the next step, and examine the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can look at a stack trace and determine which element in a `List` was `null`. If you have `null` elements in your `List`, the easiest workaround is probably to fix your `Comparator` to handle `null`(s). Also, you could use the `Comparator` to log the `null`(s). Basically, something like

```
@Override
public int compare(SingleMeasurementValuePoint point1,
        SingleMeasurementValuePoint point2) {
    if (point1 == null && point2 == null) {
        System.out.println("null point1 and point2");
        return 0;
    } else if (point1 == null) {
        System.out.println("null point1");
        return -1;
    } else if (point2 == null) {
        System.out.println("null point2");
        return 1;
    }
    int val = point1.compareTo(point2);
    if (val == 0) {
        return point1.getComponentId().compareTo(
                point2.getComponentId());
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}
```

That still won't tell you which element at what original index was `null`. If that's what you really need then you could write a method to return the index of the first `null` (or `-1`) like

```
public static <T> int findFirstNull(List<T> al) {
    for (int i = 0, len = al.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (al.get(i) == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Finally, your `catch` block(s) should log their `Exception`(s)

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    // System.out.println();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```